# How to find an element by using data-path/data-action in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Because I do have same class name for both of the (hours and minutes) increment button. 
currently I am using below class name for hour increment button, it is working fine, but since minutes increment button have same class name, it not able to get the element.

```
<span class="duration-up-arrow duration-arrow-common"></span>
```

current structure:

```
<a href="#" tabindex="-1" title="Increment Minute" class="btn dtp-increment" data-action="incrementMinutes" data-path="MINC_001"><span class="duration-up-arrow duration-arrow-common"></span></a>
```

Comment: Please crop your image better: there is too much white on it. And even better: don't include any image of XML/code: just copy-paste it in your question with an [edit].

Comment: Hi Coeur, Thanks for your input. This was my first question in stackoverflow. Next time on-words i will be more careful.

Comment: Done. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with xpath

For minutes

```
//a[@data-action='incrementMinutes']
```

For hours

```
//a[@data-action='incrementHours']
```

**Update**

in your case click the

> //a[@data-action='incrementMinutes']/span

Comment: Hi Infeam0,Thanks for your answer.  i tried with your input, but still it seems not working for me. I am attaching my code, please have a look. 
        var hours =  element(by.className('duration-up-arrow duration-arrow-common'));
        
            for (i = 0; i <5; i++) {
                hours.click();
            }
            browser.sleep(3000);
        var minutes = element(by.xpath('//a[@data-action="incrementMinutes"]'));
         
            for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
                minutes.click();
            }

Comment: can you be more specific about "not working", do you have error ? what is happening. Also use xpath for hours and minutes, do not use duplicate class 'duration-up-arrow duration-arrow-common'.

Comment: Ok, i am getting the below error:-
 WebDriverError: unknown error: Element <a href="#" tabindex="-1" title="Increment Hour" class="btn dtp-increment" data-action="incrementHours" data-path="HINC_001">...</a> is not clickable at point (666, 527).
Other element would receive the click: <td>...</td>

Comment: Hi Infern0, It is working now. Thanks for your update. Still i wanted to know one thing from you why did you add that '/span' ? It will be informative. Thanks